# sshd doesn't read included config files at startup

Tags: ssh

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ends with this line:

```
Include sshd_config.d/sftp_users.conf
```

The contents of that file are not included, however.  Including by absolute path or with a glob doesn't change anything.

To convince myself that it's really not being read, I strace'd sshd (output below).  Definitely not being read.  And yet support for `Include` is supposedly present since [7.3p1](https://superuser.com/questions/247564/is-there-a-way-for-one-ssh-config-file-to-include-another-one) and apparently [committed](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/c2bd7f74b0e0f3a3ee9d19ac549e6ba89013abaf) on 1 Feb 2020 (prior to 31 Mar 2020).

Although I can put my included files in the main `sshd_config`, it is convenient to push customisations into `sshd_config.d/*conf`.

Any suggestions why this doesn't work?

This is an ubuntu 20.04 image, fwiw.

### Update

Using the `-ddd` option to sshd,

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
```

I discovered that including with relative pathnames, which appeared to me to be spec'd to work, does not work.  Changing to an absolute pathname reports that the config is now being read:

```
debug2: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 9: new include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/sftp_users.conf
debug2: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 9: including /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/sftp_users.conf
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/sftp_users.conf
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 182
debug2: parse_server_config_depth: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/sftp_users.conf len 182
debug3: checking syntax for 'Match Group sftp_users'
```

but the pattern never matches, whereas it does match if the `Match` block is in `sshd_config` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in some versions of openssh on ubuntu 20.04.

I've written up my investigation in the bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/rkhunter/+bug/1911014).

Comment: This bug-report is about rkhunter, not about sshd.

Answer (score 4):

Something seems off. *My* fresh install of 20.04.2 LTS Server has a /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
```

That includes .conf files successfully. It's been the same for every version of LTS Server I've used. I can't comment on other images.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1162387/whats-wrong-with-my-openssh-include-directive) one needs to be careful where the Include directive is put in the config file. To summarise it is safest to put it at the top of the file, otherwise it's best to precede the `Include` directive with `Match all` directive so it doesn't inadvertently get included as part of a `Host` directive.